# AUIOClient_StartIO failed (-66628) while run on iPhone device

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, record, audiounit

I am facing the following error in Audio unit in iOS7.1.1 (device: iPhone 5).

AUIOClient_StartIO failing while attempting to play out in background
ERROR:     [0x3ce1a18c] 1202: AUIOClient_StartIO failed (-66628)
Error: -66628

Mine is a PitchDetector app, reference the "[PitchDetectorExample](https://github.com/liggitt/PitchDetectorExample)" project on GitHub (https://github.com/liggitt/PitchDetectorExample)

And i was attempting to receive audio data while in background. It is perfectly working in iOS 7 simulator, but sometimes its not working on iOS device